# Combine 2 internet lines

Tags: internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet connection using 2 modem at a time](https://superuser.com/questions/417673/internet-connection-using-2-modem-at-a-time)

I moved into an apartment where the internet is provided. Each internet connection is limited to 10mbps/10mbps. There are two ethernet outlets in the apartment. It appears that these two outlets do not share bandwidth. They each have separate IP's and usage when connected to one outlet does not seem to affect the speed of the other. I currently have a wireless router setup on one of the ethernet connections and my desktop is connected through LAN on the other.

I was wondering if it would be possible to merge the two connections into one. What would be the required hardware? Also, could I still use my wireless router with that setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can do [DSL link bonding](http://www.qualitynet.net/?page_id=994) aka link aggregation but rest assured that your speed boost won't be really as u expect. i.e not the sum of the speeds of both lines. Additionally, some ISPs restrict that by default or, some mechanisms has to be supported from their side first before you can make use of such technology.

Moreover, DSL link bonding might be not "out there" and offered in the firmware of most home consumer-grade routers. Therefore, you would typically need to make use of other opensource firmware such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) and [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) in order to unlock and configure such feature (documentation and howto do link aggregation on their website).

The link below is a comprehensive overview of setting DSL bonding up and has some benchmarks in the end as well:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBoJ12ByutY

If you know what you are doing and geeky enough, it's worth giving it a try indeed ;)