# Assign dedicated DSL modem to IP camera, but also allow it to access other modem's network

Tags: networking, router

We added a second DSL line in order to move the security camera to its own DSL connection due to bandwidth issues. Would like to connect both routers to the same switch so all network devices can be shared across across the network.

Only the security camera will be on the one router (#2). Router 1 gateway is 192.168.200.1  with 2-10 reserved.  Same in router 2, which currently has the camera plugged directly into it instead of going through the switch for obvious conflicts.

What is the best setup for router 2 to have so it can plug into the switch and access network devices on router 1? Do I need to add a second small switch for router 2 that connects to the other switch? What IP ranges should each have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet connection using 2 modem at a time](http://superuser.com/questions/417673/internet-connection-using-2-modem-at-a-time)

Answer (score 1):

1. Change Router #2's IP address to something else (e.g. 192.168.200.254).
2. Disable the DHCP server on Router #2.
3. Configure the security camera to use a static IP that is outside of Router #1's DHCP scope (e.g. 192.168.200.250) and set it's default gateway to Router #2 (192.168.200.254).
4. Connect Router #1 and Router #2 together with a switch using their LAN ports.


   All devices plugged into the switch will get their addresses from Router #1 via DHCP, and will use Router #1's Internet connection.  Only the security camera will use Router #2 for Internet because nobody else is configured to use it as their default gateway.  All devices will be able to talk to each other because they are on the same network (192.168.200.0/24).

(Make sure you disable the DHCP server on Router #2, because having two DHCP servers on a network will cause IP conflicts)